# Access class methods from another process

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am developing an event driven system which has two processes:

1. the event driven algorithm with Queue()
2. the data handler.

The data handler is a separate class that launches a secondary process which is a self-contained websocket (MySocket) that updates the data within itself. The data handler has two methods: one to fetch and modify the data from the socket and one to put the data into a queue that is used by the main event driven process. In a nutshell the script does the following:

3. Update data -> data_handler.update_market() -> put data into queue
4. Confirm signal
5. Execute
6. Repeat

Here is the data handler code snippet:

```
    import multiprocessing as mp
    class SocketDataHandler(DataHandler):
       def __init__(self, events, client, markets_list):
       """
       Initialises data handler.

       Parameters:
       events - The Event Queue.
       markets_list - A list of symbol strings.
       """
       self.events = events
       self.client = client
       self.markets_list = markets_list
       self.market_orders = []
       self.socket = None
       self.proc = None
       self.start_w_proc()

    def start_w_proc(self):
       market_list = self.markets_list[0]
       self.socket = MySocket(self.markets_list[0])
       self.proc = mp.Process(target=self.socket.run())
       self.proc.start()

    def get_market_orders(self):
       market_orders = self.socket.get_order_book()
       #...Rearrange the data
       return market_orders

    def update_market(self):
       self.market_orders = self.get_market_orders()
       self.events.put(MarketEvent())
```

The code so far seems to work i.e I am able to access the MySocket class from the main process without using multiprocessing.Manager or Value but I believe there could be a more efficient and proper way to accomplish that.

Comment: There could well be but what's `MySocket` and what's `MarketEvent`?

Comment: How about, instead of `multiprocessing`, using coroutines with [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) instead?

Comment: @JonClements MySocket is the class that contains the websocket. The Class SocketDataHandler only instantiates it as a new process and accesses its methods.

Comment: @LawrenceD'Oliveiro I don't have experience with that but would look into it.